# Using split function on XML text

Tags: vb.net, split

I am attempting to split an XML string like this,

```
"<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0"><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"><Span><Run>This is to test a split page function</Run></Span></Paragraph><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"><Span><Run>PAGE_BREAK</Run></Span></Paragraph><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"><Span><Run>This is page two</Run></Span></Paragraph><Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph><Paragraph><Run></Run></Paragraph></Section>"
```

using "PAGE_BREAK" in the string - and would have expected it to split into two arrays, but instead it's splitting it into 18. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Dim IsPageBreak As Boolean = False
        Dim vPages() As String = Nothing
        Dim vPageNumbers As Integer = 0
        If Letter_String.Contains("PAGE_BREAK") Then
            vPages = Letter_String.Split("PAGE_BREAK")
            vPageNumbers = vPages.Length
            IsPageBreak = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you would want to do that, but this is gives the results you want.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = <Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0">
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0">
                 <Span>
                     <Run>This is to test a split page function</Run>
                 </Span>
             </Paragraph>
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph>
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0">
                 <Span>
                     <Run>PAGE_BREAK</Run>
                 </Span>
             </Paragraph>
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph>
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph>
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0">
                 <Span>
                     <Run>This is page two</Run>
                 </Span>
             </Paragraph>
             <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"></Paragraph>
             <Paragraph><Run></Run></Paragraph>
         </Section>

    Dim vPages() As String = Strings.Split(xe.ToString, "PAGE_BREAK")
```

Comment: That works - it helpfully inserts vbCrLf everwhere, but after removing those and tidying up the tags so that the first page closes properly and the subsequent pages have the header substring reproduced it does the job. Thank you for your prompt reply :-) The process involves XML strings stored in a DB, fields converted at run time and then printed to PDF using iTextSharp